# Guzzle - Request body - Integer with length more than 10 turns to 0

Tags: php, symfony, integer, httprequest, guzzle

I'm using guzzle through Symfony 3. In the body of my request i have an array of integers. The problem is that if one integer has length more than 10, arrives at the Api with the value 0.

I have already checked the PHP_INT_MAX.

```
$request = new Psr7\Request($method, $uri, $headers, $body, $version);
var_dump($request->getBody()->getContents());
```

In the `var_dump()` above i'm still able to view the body of the request. Don't know what to do next..

Comment: Are you in control of the receiving end?  Is it a limitation there?  You haven't given enough info for us to help in my opinion.

Comment: No there is not any limitation. I'm hitting an api, if i try to do the request through curl i have not this problem.